# Settings AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmVarispeed for AVFoundationAudioSettings

Tags: ios, objective-c

According to these [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationAudioSettings_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009937-CH1-SW1), I can change certain settings for AVAudioPlayer, including `AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmVarispeed` setting. How would I set this value? Do I need to subclass AVAudioSetting.h?

Comment: Different constants apply to different properties in different classes. No one is going to list all of them for you. Which one are you particularly interested in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If no required use of AVAudioPlayer, you can use AVPlayer

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
playerItem.audioTimePitchAlgorithm = AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmTimeDomain;
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[player play];
```

Comment: actually a better question is, what happens if the user is iOS 6 and below?

Comment: According to your doc link, this setting only available in iOS 7+. If device is iOS6-, you should disable this function.

Comment: Why should I add anything? Good answer! However, on the theory that it is better to teach a man to fish to than to give a man a fish, let me tell you (@Apollo) how you would have found this out for yourself: in Xcode, in the documentation window, search on AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithm.